# Does order of the filter matter in AppEngine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, filter, objectify

I was wondering, does the order of the filter matters in appengine datastore?

Example, say if we have two filter: isDeleted and startDate. Does changing the order of these
two filter property matters? Or does appengine optimizes the filter automatically.

For example by filtering by isDeleted shrinks down the data smaller, then it makes sense to filter in order: isDeleted then startDate. However if you define the filter in the reverse order startDate then isDeleted, this query might be not optimized.

My question is does order of declaration of filter or index entry in the filter matters? Or this optimization is automatically done for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it matters. As I undersand it you have an index isdeleted, startdate. Dont create the index the other way arround. If you do it the other way arround, you will first filter on date but later it will have to scan all items in that date range to find those not deleted.
If you do it as I suggest you will only look at not deleted and then quickly find my date range without having to scan all.